# How to append Tokbox flash to dynamic div

Tags: javascript, opentok, tokbox

I was wondering if there was a way to pass a dynamic div id to the TB.initPublisher. I'm using the Basic tutorial as a framework to build off of, and the Flash is appended at the end of the body, rather than in the div I'd like. What I'm currently trying is:

```
session.addEventListener('sessionConnected', sessionConnectedHandler);

function sessionConnectedHandler(event, chatBoxPublisherDiv) {
publisher = TB.initPublisher(chatBoxPublisherDiv);
session.publish(publisher);
}
```

Comment: **Clarification:** chatBoxPublisherDiv is a dynamic div that is not defined until just before the Tokbox session is created. I'm not sure how to pass that div id to the sessionConnectedHandler function.

Comment: Hows is the 'dynamic div' created ? add your code for that - it should be very simple to get the `id` attribute of it ... however its created

Comment: thanks, @manseUK, It was a problem with scope - I was trying to pull in a variable without passing it to the function in the correct way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function sessionConnectHandler(event) {
    var publisherProperties = {width: 400, height:300, name:"Bob's stream"};
    publisher = TB.initPublisher(API_KEY, 'publisher', publisherProperties);
    session.publish(publisher);
}
```

where `'publisher'` is the id of the element you want the content to appear

[Docs here for `initPublisher` method](http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/api/tools/js/documentation/api/TB.html#initPublisher)